# Which cultures considered dual-gender sacred

Tags: religion, cultural-history, gender

Which cultures have historically considered the manifestation of two or more genders by one individual to be either a divine trait (being a deity) or to be an indication of divine favor or association (being a priest or prophet, etc)?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about history. . .

Comment: I am only familiar with the concept of "berdache" or "two-spirit" among American Indian tribes. (Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-Spirit). I'm not sure if other cultures have the dual-gender concept, but Wikipedia also has a lengthy article about third genders (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_gender)

Comment: @HDE226868, I'm asking in a historical context.  I don't think we have a comparative religion SE site yet...

Comment: It's not hard to see how this question could be SE compliant with just cosmetic changes. Basically, "Have any cultures historically considered dual-gender to be sacred?"

Comment: @twosheds, I thought that was implied, but I added a variation on "with history" to defuse more criticism in that vein.  I am quite familiar with the debate, having been active on SO. :)

Comment: I also just created a "gender" tag for this question. Considering how popular the concept is in academic history, I was surprised to find it hadn't been used on this site yet!

Comment: @twosheds, I would have created a gender tag, when I asked it, but I only get 100 xp out of being established on SO.

Comment: 1. Do you mean hermaphroditic? 2. Do you mean that having two genders signified divinity? Because the other construction could be- Are there divine beings with 2 genders? Then of course there are such characters in mythology. Also transgender, shifting gender, cross-dressing, sex change etc. are to be found in mythology.

Comment: Unless the question is rephrased to focus on a specific historical society's treatment of "dual-gender" (and as @Rajib pointed out, please explain what this is supposed to mean), this seems to be an anthropology list-type question.

Comment: Of course this is about history. The ancient Greeks had stories about the soothsayer Tiresias. He was born a man, but after seeing a pair of snakes copulating he was transformed into a woman, married and had children. Seven years later, after seeing the copulating snakes a second time he turned back into a man, but was blind, and had prophetic powers. There are lots of variants to the story, but they all link Tiresias's sacred powers with his hermaphrodism.

Comment: I thought I was pretty clear--"the manifestation of two or more genders by an individual".  Is there ambiguity about that?
As far as a list-type question, I wasn't aware there are problems with that.  There are certainly other questions here that start "What cultures [did something]", and they are getting positive participation.

Comment: This is a list question, and a bad [list](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/q/667) question.  I'm afraid that I must respectfully disagree that "manifestation of two or more genders by an individual" is clear or commonly accepted. While there are questions of the form, "Which cultures do X?", they really don't fit SE format well; there is no way to objectively judge the answers, and they tend to generate lots of comments & argument and very little learning.

Comment: Many societies had double or trans gender characters, (and this was answered) but I can't remember any where a double or trans gender person would have any good and religion related social role. (And I have the impression that this is the true question here)

Comment: Do you mean like the Christian God?

Answer (score 5):

If we accept mythological and "divine" figures as having "divinity" or being "sacred", here is a short list from the Hindu pantheon, and by no means exhaustive:

[Ila](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ila_%28Hinduism%29): Is both sexes, changing sex seasonally. Married to Budh or Mercury-God (planet Mercury). Goes through many transformations.

> In the Ramayana, the Linga Purana and the Mahabharata, Ila grows to
>   become the king of Bahlika. While hunting in a forest, Ila
>   accidentally trespassed Sharavana ("Forest of Reeds"), the sacred
>   grove of the goddess Parvati, the consort of the god Shiva. Upon
>   entering Sharavana, all male beings except for Shiva, including trees
>   and animals, are transformed into females. In the Ramayana, even Shiva
>   had assumed the form of a female to please the goddess. One legend
>   tells that a female yakshini disguised herself as a deer and
>   purposefully led Ila to the grove in order to save her husband from
>   the king. The Linga Purana and the Mahabharata emphasize the sex
>   change of Ila to be a deliberate act of Shiva to start the Lunar
>   Dynasty. The Bhagavata Purana et al. texts tell that Ila's entire
>   entourage as well as his horse also changed their genders.

[Ardhanarishvara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ardhanarishvara): Made of Both Shiva and his consort Parvati, usually depicted as split through the middle. Right half is usually male- Shiva. Some say it is the representation of unity/yin-yang/completeness.

> Ardhanarishvara represents the synthesis of masculine and feminine
>   energies of the universe (Purusha and Prakriti) and illustrates how
>   Shakti, the female principle of God, is inseparable from (or the same
>   as, according to some interpretations) Shiva, the male principle of
>   God. The union of these principles is exalted as the root and womb of
>   all creation.

[Shikhandi/Amba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shikhandi): Born in one life as Amba, she comes back as ambiguous/female Shikhandi to take revenge on Bhisma.

During the great battle at Kurukshetra, Bhishma is unable to fight Shikhandi, who is fighting as a man, but whom Bhishma knows to be a woman.

> According to C. Rajagopalachari's Mahabharata summary, when
>   Shikhandini was still a young woman she discovered the garland of
>   ever-blooming blue lotuses hung on the palace gate. Shikhandini put it
>   around her neck. Actually it was Amba (now Shikhandini) who had hung
>   the garland given to her by Lord Kartikeya. When Drupada saw his
>   daughter wearing the garland, he quaked with fear at the thought of
>   becoming Bhishma's enemy and Shikhandini was banished from the
>   kingdom. She performed austerities in the forest and was transformed
>   into a male named Shikhandi. According to Vyasa Mahabharata
>   Shikhandini exchanged her sex with a Yaksha.

[Arjuna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arjuna): The hero of Mahabharata also changes gender. Urvashi cursed Arjuna when he refused her advances, that he would become a "kliba", or of third gender. Arjuna used this as a disguise during his last year of exile, taking the name Brihannala and living as a woman.

[Vishnu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishnu): Changes gender and becomes "Mohini" (the enchantress) to trick the demons into giving up "Amrita" the nectar of immortality. Vishnu as Mohini became pregnant from Shiva, and gave birth to Ayyappa.

> According to Tamil versions of the Mahabharata, the god Krishna – an
>   incarnation of Vishnu – also took the form of Mohini and married
>   Aravan. This was in order to give Aravan the chance to experience love
>   before his death, as he had volunteered to be sacrificed. Krishna
>   remained in mourning in the Mohini form for some time after Aravan's
>   death. This marriage and death of Aravan are commemorated annually in
>   a rite known as Thali, during which Hijra (Indian "third gender") take
>   on the role of Krishna-Mohini and "marry" Aravan in a mass-wedding,
>   followed by an 18-day festival.

Other Characters:

**Iravan/Aravan**: God of transgender community and the Drapadi cults. Also married Mohini (sex-changed Vishnu).

[Yuvanashva](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pregnant_King): The pregnant King.

**Sthunakarna**: The yaksha who [exchanged sex](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=izFNswlJ9LMC&pg=PA388&lpg=PA388&dq=sthunakarna&source=bl&ots=qoslSnf801&sig=ixv2cESFysecHdbI3dPsTCQzm8k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wlaIVJOKNYGTuASJk4C4Bg&sqi=2&ved=0CDoQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=sthunakarna&f=false) with Shikhandi.

Se also [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGBT_themes_in_Hindu_mythology#Gender_variance_of_deities).

Comment: It was not clear what "dual gender" means in the question, so I have given transformed gender examples as well.